# loop php $_POST array names

Tags: php, arrays, post, while-loop

I would like to loop 5 arrays in post.
What should be the right code to display: 
$_POST["fp0"]
$_POST["fp1"]
..
$_POST["fp5"]
in a loop?

```
$x = 0;
while($x <= 5) {
 $fp = ${'_POST["fp'.$x.'"]'};
 echo $fp.'<br>';
 $x++;
}
```

Comment: `echo $_POST['fp' . $i]`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$x = 0;
while($x <= 5) {
 $fp = $_POST["fp$x"];
 echo $fp.'<br>';
 $x++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

0 to 5 are six numbers, so you want to loop 6 elements in an array,

this is what you want

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++ ){
    echo $_POST['fp'.$i]."<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by `for` loop, you form must `POST` values for

> fp0, fp1 .... fp5

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $fp = $_POST['fp'.$i];
    echo $fp . "<br>";
}
```